# Woking with colfit in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I wanted to calculate the histogram n local histogram equalisation of an input image, using colfit. But when i run the code i get the following error.
??? Error using ==> ge
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> colfilt at 135
if all(block>=size(a)), % Process the whole matrix at once.

Error in ==> localhist at 10
z=colfilt(f,[w w],'sliding',@std);

Please provide some insights.

Comment: Can you show the inputs (and the sizes of the inputs) that you passed to the colfilt function please?

Comment: colfilt(f,[3 3],'sliding',@std); w is the neighbourhood window size input by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen it written on the documentation (neither on `help colfilt` nor on `docs colfilt`), but I think you can only use `colfilt`, as `nlfilter`, with monochannel images. So that if you try to run the example code provided on `help colfilt` on a 3-channel image, say:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');  % 'peppers.png' is just a demo color image usually provided with matblab
figure, imshow(I)
I2 = uint8(colfilt(I,[5 5],'sliding',@mean));
figure, imshow(I2)
```

You get the kind of error that you posted:

> Error using  >= 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in colfilt (line 135)
>      if all(block>=size(a)), % Process the whole matrix at once.

If you thry this instead, which only takes the first channel (or any other combination of the channels) it will just work

```
% which is one of the example images usually provided with matlab
J = imread('peppers.png');
I = J(:,:,1);
figure, imshow(I)
I2 = uint8(colfilt(I,[5 5],'sliding',@mean));
figure, imshow(I2)
```

I hope this helps